# File download and Thanks page call in one button press

Tags: php, download

I have a downloads page on a site with links to lots of ZIP files. I want to allow the user to click the  download button to download the ZIP file - additionally when they click the  button I want the browser to re-direct the user to a thanks page.

Is this possible? The site is PHP based if that helps!

I've read that you can't do this on one press, so the  needs to call the downloads-thanks page, and then serve the download file function from the thanks page... How is that possible if I have loads of download buttons/files though? Would need to send a variable from the downloads page to the downloads-thanks page to allow the thanks page to process the correct file to download???

********** update **********

OK, I have had a go at implementing the PHP variable and GET function - but am having no joy, the code is as below and a link to the live example here - http://www.example.biz/clients/example/downloads/ - The call to load the thanks page gets ignored and I just get prompted to save the file download???

Downloads page:

```
    <a href="http://www.example.biz/clients/example/downloads/thanks.php?file=zip1">zip1</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.biz/clients/example/downloads/thanks.php?file=zip2">zip2</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.biz/clients/example/downloads/thanks.php?file=zip3">zip3</a>
```

thanks.php page:

```
    <?php
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    if($file == "zip1")
    {
    header("Location: http://www.example.biz/clients/example/downloads/zip1.zip");
    }
    else if($file == "zip2")
    {
    header("Location: http://www.example.biz/clients/example/downloads/zip2.zip");
    }
    else if($file == "zip3")
    {
    header("Location: http://www.example.biz/clients/example/downloads/zip3.zip");
    }

    echo "Thankyou for downloading";

    ?>
```

********** update 2 *********

Have abandoned PHP as the actual PHP download page never gets to render on screen - it serves up the correct download but the thanks page never renders... Went with a JS solution as below:

```
    <script>
    function thanks() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.location.pathname = "thanks.html";
        }, 1000);
    }
    </script>

    <a href="zip1.zip" onclick="thanks()">zip1</a>
```

Comment: This is sooo possible all you have todo is pass the download link to the thank you page and then invoke the download with a meta refresh tag to the download....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you redirect from your thanks page to file download link.
When browser handle download link, it doesn't change html document view.

You can do it with javascript.

Comment: JS was the way to go here - much easier to implement ;]

Comment: better solution to start download on thanks page, you can see implementation an most of downloading pages. First you see thanks page with text "download shortly begins if it not - press link". in future with that mechanism you can implement download sessions and what you ever want.

Comment: Thanks Electronick - Do you have any example links I can take a look at? The tricky thing I have is that I have lots of download files - so would need to use variables to allow just one thanks page to render which then fires specific files to download based on the variable sent with the thanks page url

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vlc/files/2.0.0/win32/vlc-2.0.0-win32.exe/download

Comment: In fact, it works a little harder, but I think you can use a simplified approach.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines?

**Download Page**

```
<a href="thankyou.php?file=zip1">zip1</a>
<a href="thankyou.php?file=zip2">zip2</a>
<a href="thankyou.php?file=zip3">zip3</a>
```

**Thankyou Page**

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];

if($file == "zip1")
{
   header("Location: http://domain.com/zip1.zip");
}
else if($file == "zip2")
{
   header("Location: http://domain.com/zip1.zip");
}

echo "Thankyou for downloading";

?>
```

Comment: Sounds good! Will give it a try! Sorry - I thought Stackoverflow was a place where peeps could get help of code problems?

Comment: PHP solution did not work?? Went with a jQuery function instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass `$_GET` values to the thanks page...
i.e when a user clicks a button, the button has a form or javascript's `window.location` function which will redirect the user to thanks page, you can pass `$_GET` value easily like:

```
http://www.somthing.com/thanks-download-page.php?fileid=1
```

and from the `thanks-download-page.php` you can read the `$_GET['fileid']` value, then pass that value to a db or whatever you want to get details of the file location...